# SSIS - DB Destination Dynamic Table Name

Tags: dynamic, ssis

After creating tables A, B, C with Control Flow in ssis package, reading Excel with Data Flow.
I want to put the data in tables A, B, C generated after processing.

Control Flow (Create table (A,B,C)) -> Data Flow (Read Excel File -> split -> insert table (A,B,C))

**Control Flow**

[image]

**Data Flow**

[image]

**Create Question Table SQL Script functoid**

[image: Question table]

**Destination error message**

[image: Invalid object error]

I think that Dynamic Table is necessary.  please help you how to connect to .

Comment: One more thing - Why are you creating your table in your SQL Task? You do it only once - Why dont you just create them, and then select them from the list instead? Unless there is some logic before i cannot see why

Comment: I just reproduced your scenario and it's fine unless the tables have never been created before - in this case the package validation will fail. I second @Thomas inquiry if you really need to create these tables. Could it be that you just want those tables to be cleared before inserting your data?

Comment: Agree with @Filburt - I also just tried to recreate the scenario and i dont have any errors. Only when the table doesnt exists. Furthermore if you have same tablename under different Schemas, you might not insert into the right one. So have that in mind. Its good practice to declare schema-name infront of your tablename

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'll try it tomorrow(declare schema-name). and I will add comment tomorrow. @ Filburt @ Thomas Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Check if your tables is created first. Its the most crucial.

Comment: I declared schema-name. So I solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the variables holding the desired taget table name in your Destination Table configuration.

On the `Connection Manager` page of your Destinations, just select `Tabel name or view name variable` from the *Data access mode* dropdown option.

Then select the variable holding the desired table name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but If i select 'Table name or view name variable', "Invalid object name" problem occurs.

Comment: Can you please show the content of your `Create Question Table`, `Create Option Table` and `Create Response Table` SQL Script functoids? It sounds like those variables are not in sync with table names you use there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I uploaded 「Create Question table」,「Invalid object name」. Could you please check it?

Comment: The status message suggests that the Destination functiod lost the column mappings. Switch to the *Mappings* page and adjust the column mapping.

Comment: No filburt - It cannot find his table, either because he didnt create it or because his variables are set wrong. The mapping warning is standard when you havent mapped anything. But he cannot map anything because he cannot refer to his table. Properbly due to invalid tablename which i wrote in my comment to the answer

Comment: @Thomas From what can be seen, the Data Flow is only executed after sucessfully creating all 3 tables and the variable values match the SQL script so we have to assume things are correct as far as we can see.

Comment: No -  His variables is set wrong. He needs to provide schema name

Comment: @Thomas No, he doesn't have to. He only uses one connection so there is little chance to create and then access tables in different schemas.

Comment: Ahhh youre right -  But its good practice to enter schema-name as it will fail if he has several Questions tables.